# Output the name of the current DLL being acted on using MSBuild

Tags: dll, msbuild

This is probably a really stupid MSBuild question but if I have

```
<ItemGroup>
<Dll Include="<Path_to_DLLs>\*.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And then

```
<SomeTarget useFiles=@(Dll)>
....do stuff
</someTarget>
```

What I want to do is to output the current item that `@(Dll)` is looping through. Basically I wanting to output the name of the current DLL being acted on.

I think this must be possible and it is probably so simple but it is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha The joys of metadata.

On the creation of every item in MSBuild, specific MetaData is assigned to it.

In this case I could use %(Filename) to retrieve the file name

[This is a full list of Well Known metaData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx)